# Visual Studio Extension: Track when new code window is opened?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions

I'm trying to write a Visual Studio Extension that tracks when a new code window is opened. I found a class `IVsCodeWindowEvents` that seems to provide listener methods for that:

```
public int OnNewView(IVsTextView pView)
```

However, I have a problem that I don't know how to register to listen to these events.

My class looks like this:

```
public sealed class VSTrackerPackage : Package, IVsCodeWindowEvents
```

In this class, I implement the OnNewView method, but how can I register this listener in my `Initialize` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can register for Visual Studio events via the [DTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/envdte.dte(v=vs.110).aspx) and more specifically [DTE2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/envdte80.dte2.aspx).

First step is to get access from your Package via the `Initialize` method:

```
public sealed class VSTrackerPackage : Package
{
    DTE2 dte = GetService(typeof (DTE)) as DTE2;
}
```

At this point, I'd recommend attaching to the [DocumentEvents.DocumentOpened](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.documenteventsclass.documentopened.aspx) event.  From there you can check if it's a document you are interested in or not.  You can also get the Window if you need to interact with it there:

```
_dte.Events.DocumentEvents.DocumentOpened += document =>
        {
            //double check this logic.
            if (document.Language != "C#")
                return;

            //do work


            //or - load window document.ActiveWindow.
        };
```

If it helps, I have an open source Visual Studio plugin (shameluss plug: [pMixins](http://www.pmixins.com) ) that attaches to a number of VS events.  Relevant class is on GitHub:  https://github.com/ppittle/pMixins/blob/master/CopaceticSoftware.CodeGenerator.StarterKit/Infrastructure/VisualStudioEventProxy.cs.  Class definition starts on line 243.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked great! But now I have already the next problem. I want to get notified when a new method is selected in the code window. I have a reference to the DropDownBarManager, but there seems to be no DropDownBar associated. Is there any other easy why to register to these kind of events?

Comment: This sounds like a new question!  Write it up and post the link here and I'll see what I can do to help.

Comment: Thanks a lot, help would be great. Here is the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28323730/visual-studio-extension-how-to-track-when-a-new-method-is-edited