# Visual Studio Extension: How to track when a new method is edited?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions

For my Visual Studio Extension, I'm trying to track what methods are selected by the user. To do that, I thought it would be a good idea, to observe the DropDownBar, and track all changes to this bar. So, I started to look for new documents beeing opened, get the IvDropDownBarManager object to get the DropDownBar object:

```
private void OnDocumentOpened(EnvDTE.Document document)
{
   IVsUIShell uiShell = (IVsUIShell)GetService(typeof(SVsUIShell));
   IEnumWindowFrames ppenum; uiShell.GetDocumentWindowEnum(out ppenum);
   IVsWindowFrame[] frames = new IVsWindowFrame[1]; 
   uint numFrames; IVsWindowFrame m_frame = null; 
   while (ppenum.Next(1, frames, out numFrames) == VSConstants.S_OK && numFrames == 1)
   { 
      m_frame = frames[0] as IVsWindowFrame; 
      object title;
      m_frame.GetProperty((int)__VSFPROPID.VSFPROPID_Caption, out title);
      if ((title as String).ToLowerInvariant() == document.ActiveWindow.Caption.ToLowerInvariant())
         break;
    } 
    object docView;
    m_frame.GetProperty((int)__VSFPROPID.VSFPROPID_DocView, out docView); 
    IVsCodeWindow codeWindow = docView as IVsCodeWindow;
    IVsDropdownBarManager dropdown = (IVsDropdownBarManager)codeWindow;

    IVsDropdownBar bar;
    dropdown.GetDropdownBar(out bar);
}
```

However, there are a few issues:

1) While I'm able to get the IVsDropdownBarManager object, the IVsDropdownBar seems to always be null. Why is this the case?

2) Even when I would be able to get the IVsDropdownBar object, what should I do next? There isn't any place where I could add a listener.

3) Is this way too complicate and would there be an easier way to do the same thing?

Comment: Visual Studio 2014? Despite the tag apparently existing, there's no such product. There's 2012, 2013, and 2015 is currently in preview (and older versions that 2012, of course)

Comment: Sorry my mistake, fixed the tags.

Comment: I think there's an event in a `DocumentWindow` that fires when the text cursor moves.  You could attach to that and then check the Dropdown bar, although not sure if you're event handler would fire before the Dropdown bar is updated.  

As to why the Dropdown is null, in my experience with coding against VS, you often need to cast the object to something else (generally a concrete class) before you can get much use out of it.